# binomial expansion for non integer exponent $n$

Tags: taylor-expansion, binomial-theorem

Does there exist an approximation of the term $(x+a)^n$ for non-integer $n$, but for any $x>0$. I've found many topics concerning this but they cite that the binomial expansion is valid only for $|x|<|a|$.

Comment: If $|x|> |a|$, why not just flip $x$ and $a$?

Comment: @Macavity, what is the advantage of flipping $x$ and $a$?

Comment: @CAGT well, if you have an expansion for one case, the flipped one will give you the expansion for the other case.  E.g. for $|a| < |x|$, we have $$(x+a)^n = x^n\left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)^n = x^n\sum_{k \in \mathbb Z^+} \binom{n}k\left(\frac{a}x\right)^k$$ OTOH, if $|x|< |a|$, switch them in the formula.

Comment: @Macavity actually this is the series representation of $f(a)=(x+a)^n$ and not as function of $x$

Comment: @Macavity, ohh, I see, he gets rid of the restriction!  Thanks.

Comment: Wasn't this asked recently on the site--with the same answers as below?

Comment: Yes, you can do it as long as the binomial piece is just a "correction" factor. The issue is really only when $|x|=|a|$.

Comment: I tried to plot the exact expression $(x+a)^n$ and the approximative one by infinite series until a certain k, the 2 curves match perfectly when -a<x<a, raising the x the approximative form behaves differently

Comment: @Elmehdi - the binomial expansion for non-integer $n$ only converges for $|x| < |a|$. When $|x| > |a|$, you should use the expansion that Macavity shows, which converges then. And when $|x| = |a|$, you have $0$ or $(2a)^n$.